# How to read a value from a json file in AWS Codepipeline?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-step-functions

**My question:** How can Codepipeline read the value of a field in a json file which is in `SourceCodeArtifact`?

I have Gthub repo that contains a file `imageManifest.json` which looks like this:

```
{
  "image_id": "docker.pkg.github.com/my-org/my-repo/my-app",
  "image_version": "1.0.1"
}
```

I want my AWS Codepipeline Source stage to be able to read the value of `image_version` from `imageManifest.json` and pass it as a parameter to a CloudFormation action in a subsequent stage of my pipeline.

For reference, here is my source stage.

```
        Stages:
        - Name: GitHubSource
          Actions:
          - Name: SourceAction
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Source
              Owner: ThirdParty
              Version: '1'
              Provider: GitHub
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: SourceCodeArtifact
            Configuration:
              Owner: !Ref GitHubOwner
              Repo: !Ref GitHubRepo
              OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubAuthToken
```

And here is my deploy stage:

```
        - Name: DevQA
          Actions:
          - Name: DeployInfrastructure
            InputArtifacts:
              - Name: SourceCodeArtifact
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Deploy
              Owner: AWS
              Provider: CloudFormation
              Version: '1'
            Configuration:
              StackName: !Ref AppName
              Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
              RoleArn: !GetAtt [CloudFormationRole, Arn]
              ParameterOverrides: !Sub '{"ImageId": "${image_version??}"}'
```

Note that `image_version` in the last line above is just my aspirational placeholder to illustrate how I hope to use the `image_version` json value.

How can Codepipeline read the value of a field in a json file which is in `SourceCodeArtifact`?
StepFunctions?  Lambda?  CodeBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CodeBuild step in between Source and Deploy stages.

In CodeBuild step, read the `image_version` from SourceArtifact (artifact produced by soruce stage) and write to an artifact 'Template configuration' file [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html#w2ab1c13c14b7) which is a configuration property of the CloudFormation action. This file can hold parameter values for your CloudFormation stack. Use this file instead of `ParameterOverrides` you are currently using.

Comment: This is an interesting idea!  We currently use a template configuration file so I could use CodeBuild to add an additional parameter to it and then pass that output artifact to the CloudFormation action.  Thank you!

Comment: I posed the same question to AWS Support and I received a very similar suggestion from them this morning, so I'm accepting this as an answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Fn::GetParam` is what you want. It can returns a value from a key-value pair in a JSON-formatted file. And the JSON file must be included in an artifact.

Here is the documentation and it gives you some examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html#w2ab1c13c20b9

It should be something like:

```
ParameterOverrides: |
    {
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::GetParam" : ["SourceCodeArtifact", "imageManifest.json", "image_id"]}
    }
```

Comment: This would be perfect but, for the life of me, I can't get it to work in conjunction with !Sub.  I have a number of ParameterOverrides that I wish to use.
```
ParameterOverrides: !Sub |
                    {
                      "AppName": "${AppName}",
                      "ImageVersion": { "Fn:GetParam": [ "InfraSourceCode", "imageManifest.json", "image_version" ] }
                    }
```
In this case, the string with GetParam is not evaluated.  I have tried a number of different ways of using GetParam.  Any help is appreciate.

Comment: @rodoherty1 Have you tried put !Sub inside it? Like ```ParameterOverrides: | { "AppName" : { "Fn::Sub" : "AppName" }, "ImageId" : { "Fn::GetParam" : ["SourceCodeArtifact", "imageManifest.json", "image_id"]}  }```
I have not tried it but I feel it can work.

Comment: I haven't tried that exact code block but I think the problem is that it doesn't evaluate `"ImageId" : { "Fn::GetParam" : ["SourceCodeArtifact", "imageManifest.json", "image_id"]}`.  So even if `"AppName" : { "Fn::Sub" : "AppName"}` is evaluated, I don't think  `Fn::GetParam` will be.  This morning I received a suggestion from AWS which is very similar to the answer from @shariqmaws so I'll try that out.  Thank you for your suggestions, LiuChang.